# How to launch node from install directory

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**What I wanted**

I want to reduce my docker image size through removing a cloned source code from my workspace in 'src' directory according to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/269046/is-it-possible-to-run-nodes-without-source/) suggestion. For that matter, I have just deployed my source code using the following commands:

```
    # install package
   sudo catkin config --install
   catkin_make
   catkin_make install
```

**The problem**

As a result, three folder have been generated inside 'catking_ws' workspace it self. Namely, build, devel and install. *install*  directory generate with many other library folders. I then navigated in to */share/* folder and tried to *roslaunch*  one of my launch file. This is the error that I got:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [oxford_gps_eth/gps_node]: oxford_gps_eth
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...

**Expectation**

I was able to launch my node, even being in */install/share/* directory without removing the cloned source code in *'src'* directory.
I wanted to launch my nodes after building and remove my source code so that I can utilize my image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385110/how-to-launch-node-from-install-directory/) by [Zekarias Taye Hirpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/82070/zekarias-taye-hirpo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got an answer. Source this file

```
source install/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Zekarias Taye Hirpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/82070/zekarias-taye-hirpo/) with karma: 31 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-25**:
Yes, that's exactly the same as you do when you `source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash` :)